# Passing a service as input in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to create a generic list component that contains several features I want all my lists to have. Ideally I would like to use different services as input to the component to render different data sets. Is this possible in angular 2?

Modfying the example from the angular 2 docs

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Generic List',
    template: 
    `
    <h2>Items</h2>
    <ul class="items">
      <li *ngFor="let item of items"
          [class.selected]="isSelected(item)"
          (click)="onSelect(item)">
        <span class="badge">{{item.id}}</span> {{item.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    `
})
export class GTComponent {
    @Input() someService: Service;

     items: Item[];
     private selectedId: number;

    isSelected(item: Item) { return item.id === this.selectedId; }

    onSelect(item: Item) {
    }
}
```

If this is possible, how would I populate the items array with data from the service if the service has some function named `getItems()` that returns a promise.

Comment: You need to use 'isMulti', which injects an array of services to the constructor. You then search the array for the one your component needs, possibly using an enum that is set on the services, and also on each component as an input. Do the search in ngOnInit

Answer (score 6):

I had the same need and in the end I managed to do the implementation, which so far seems to work well.
The implementation is written in **Angular 8**.

#### 1. Defining services

All the services that will be passed as `@Input` to the child component should have a method called `getItems()`, so, firstly, I've created an abstract class that holds nothing but the definitions of the method. This class is really no more than a container that informs Angular about the `getItems()` method:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class ItemsService {

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Returns a list of all items
   */
  abstract getItems(): Observable<Item[]>;

}
```

Then, we can create our services (`ItemsAService`, `ItemsBService`, `ItemsCService`), that will implement `ItemsService`, as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ItemsService } from './items.service';
import { Item } from './item';

const ITEMS_A: Item[] = [
  // our items collection
];


@Injectable()
export class ItemsAService implements ItemsService {

  constructor() { }

  getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return of(ITEMS_A);
    // of(ITEMS_A) returns an Observable<Item[]> that emits the array of mock items.
    // in real life, you'll call HttpClient.get<Item[]>() which also returns an Observable<Item[]>:
   // return this.httpClient.get<Item[]>
  }

}
```

... same code for `ItemsBService` and `ItemsCService`.

More info about creating interfaces for Angular Services [here](https://medium.com/hackernoon/creating-interfaces-for-angular-services-1bb41fbbe47c).

#### 2. Parent component

Our generic list component will be included from a parent component. In this parent component, we'll inject the services described above, as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsAService } from './items-a.service';
import { ItemsBService } from './items-b.service';
import { ItemsCService } from './items-c.service';

@Component({
  ...
})

export class AppComponent  {
 
 constructor(
   public itemsAService: ItemsAService,
   public itemsBService: ItemsBService,
   public itemsCService: ItemsCService
 )  { }

}
```

Then, in template, we have:

```
<app-generic-list
  name="A"
  [service]="itemsAService"
>
</app-generic-list>

<app-generic-list
  name="B"
  [service]="itemsBService"
>
</app-generic-list>

<app-generic-list
  name="C"
  [service]="itemsCService"
>
</app-generic-list>
```

#### 3. Generic list component

This component we'll have an `@Input() service`, type `ItemsService` and we'll call the `getItems()` method from the service in the `ngOnInit()` hook:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ItemsService } from '../items.service';
import { Item } from '../item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-generic-list',
  ...
})

export class GenericListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   @Input() name: string;
   @Input() service: ItemsService;

  items: Item[];
  subscription: Subscription;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.service) return;
    this.subscription = this.service.getItems()
      .subscribe(items => this.items = items);
  }

  // other methods here

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Note that the parent component and the child (generic list) component will share the same instance of the service.

---

#### Full example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgubup

---

I'm looking forward to know if there's another more preferred method to implement this.

Comment: There are other ways I've discovered to handle this situation since this question was posted. I prefer to use Dependency Injection with polymorphism to handle this specific case now.

Comment: But is there not a  Dependency Injection with polymorphism above?

Comment: @JME can you post said method so we can see what you've done?